# Which permissions does a service account need to deploy to App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have project **A** that is an App Engine Standard nodejs8 app. And I have project **B** which has a VM GCE machine with Jenkins on it - that is our builder that's supposed to deploy all other project when commit happens.

I can deploy just fine from **B** to **A** using `appcfg.py update .` But if I try to deploy using `gcloud deploy app` I get this error:

`Permissions error fetching application [apps/my-project]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project.`

I've added the service account associated with the Jenkins machine to project **A** and went as far as to give it owner permissions. I also enabled App Engine API on both projects.

Which permission am I missing?

Comment: Which `appcfg.py` is that (there can be several of them)? Are those the exact commands or do you have other args as well? Are both commands executed in the app source, with the same userid/credentials (the jenkins user?) and in the same way (i.e. both manually or scripted, interactive or  not)?

Comment: I would suggest running "$gcloud init [service account]" (where [service account] is the service account you added in Project A) first and then try to deploy the app. It is possible that you did not initiate the correct account when trying to deploy the app to Project A.

Comment: @DanCornilescu `appcfg.py update .` no other arguments. It's the appcfg.py in `google_appengine` folder. Both commands are executed from Jenkins (I also tried from cmd, they behave the same)

Comment: @Jason I did the `gcloud init account` routine, and I see the service account as the active account (with an asterisk by it's left side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, issue solved. In addition to granting all relevant permissions to the service account in project A, needed to enable access to all APIs on the VM itself (in project B).